# Git on windows : weird character on first line for C# file

Tags: git

Using http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe&can=2&q= GUI when viewing a c# file I get this:

```
+ï»¿using System;
+using System.Collections.Generic;
+using System.Linq;
+using System.Text;
```

Is **+ï»¿** normal characters?

Comment: Isn't this a diff, not a "view" of the file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ï»¿` is what the unicode character U+FEFF encoded as UTF-8 looks like when you "assume" the encoding is actually ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1).

U+FEFF is zero-width non-breaking space but this usage is deprecated and is normally used as a byte-order mark (BOM) in *character encoding schemes* which have multibyte *code units* as the byte swapped version: U+FFFE is not a valid unicode character.

As UTF-8 is just a sequence of bytes it makes no sense to have a byte order mark but some tools still use the character as a UTF-8 "signature".

Answer (score 4):

It is the Unicode byte order mark.
So the software that is showing you the text is displaying the BOM instead of skipping it.

Answer (score 3):

Theses characters are the BOM (Byte Order Mark) of the encoded file.

UTF-8 files can be encoded with or without BOM. You can do the conversion with tools like "Notepad++".